# oracle bulk delete : delete from table where column in array

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to collect an array of revisions numbers. 
I will use to delete records in multiple audit tables.
So I wrote a plsql to collect that array and to run delete on other tables based on condition using that array

```
declare 
  type NumberArray is table of number index by binary_integer;
  revisions NumberArray;
Begin
  select rev bulk collect into revisions from (
    select t.rev, row_number() over (partition by 
        column1,
        column2
        order by column3) rn
    from table1 t)
  where rn <> 1;

  dbms_output.put_line(revisions.count || ' records found from table2 to be deleted');
  delete from table2 where rev in (revisions);
  dbms_output.put_line('deleted from table2');
```

I am getting

```
 PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
 *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Datatype of rev is number in table1.

Comment: Why PL/SQL when you could do it simply in SQL?

Comment: data is very huge.. i want to running time

Comment: If data is huge, then context switching will be huge, PL/SQL will be slower, much slower than SQL.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good candidate for [FORALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#sthref985) statement

```
declare 
  type NumberArray is table of number(10) index by binary_integer;
  revisions NumberArray;
Begin
  select rev bulk collect into revisions from (
    select t.rev, row_number() over (partition by 
        column1,
        column2
        order by column3) rn
    from table1 t)
  where rn <> 1;

  dbms_output.put_line(revisions.count || ' records found from table2 to be deleted');
  forall i in revisions.first .. revisions.last
       delete from table2 where rev = revisions(i);
  dbms_output.put_line('deleted from table2');
End;
```

But if you still insist on using IN condition, you have to define your type at schema level:

```
create type NumberArray as table of number;
```

and then use it like this

```
declare 
  revisions NumberArray;
Begin
  select rev bulk collect into revisions from (
    select t.rev, row_number() over (partition by 
        column1,
        column2
        order by column3) rn
    from table1 t)
  where rn <> 1;

  dbms_output.put_line(revisions.count || ' records found from table2 to be deleted');
  delete from table2 where rev in (select column_value from table(revisions));
  dbms_output.put_line('deleted from table2');
End;
```

Answer (score 3):

It must be this one:

```
delete from table2 where rev MEMBER OF revisions;

or 

delete from table2 where rev =ANY (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(revisions));

or 

forall i in revisions.FIRST..revisions.LAST
delete from table2 where rev = revisions(i);

or 

delete from table2 where rev =ANY (
select rev 
from (
    select t.rev, row_number() over (partition by 
        column1,
        column2
        order by column3) rn
    from table1 t)
  where rn <> 1
);

or (not the preferred way of doing it)

for i in revisions.FIRST..revisions.LAST LOOP
   delete from table2 where rev = revisions(i);
END LOOP;
```

As already written by Marcin Wroblewski, the nested table has to be created on Schema level.

Answer (score 1):

And why would you do it in **PL/SQL** when it could be done in plain **SQL**? You are unnecessarily introducing **context switching** between both the engines.

All that PL/SQL code is nothing but a simple **DELETE statement** -

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE rev IN(
   SELECT rev FROM(
      select t.rev, row_number() over (partition by 
              column1,
              column2
              order by column3) rn
      from table1 t)
  where rn <> 1
);
```